# Law of Sines - Not Working?

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Sorry that I cannot post a picture (I don't have 10 rep), so this might be confusing. Basically, I had a bunch of lines, two parallel, and 2 transverse lines going through them, making a triangle. The triangle only has an angle and 2 sides. However, since two of the lines are parallel, I am able to figure out that one of the angles of the triangle is 40 degrees, and another is 70 degrees.

Problem Now:

Lets say I now have $\triangle {ABC}$

- $\angle A = 40 ^\circ $
- $AB = 10 $
- $\angle B = 70 ^\circ $
- $BC = 7$
- $\angle C = 70 ^\circ $
- ** Find CA **

Using my head, I know the answer for CA is 10, since this is an isosceles triangle. However, what I don't get is why Law of Sines doesn't work here. What I did was set $\frac{\sin 40}{7} = \frac {sin(70)}{x}$. Solving for $x$, I got 10.23. Is it supposed to do this, or did I just mess up somewhere?

Comment: There is no such triangle.

Comment: Ok, so can a triangle with angles 40,70,70 with side length 7,10,10 not exist? If so that kinda makes sense to me. Its sad cause this question was on Khan Academy.

Comment: There can be no such triangle in a Euclidean plane. But perhaps the original problem is not quite the one in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are correct. If the question were: *Is this triangle possible in flat Euclidean space?* your answer would be *No* and your proof would be based on the law of sines.

Now, for fun, try to create a triangle with segments in this proportion. What happens?

Answer (score 0):

You are imposing too much information on your triangle.

It is not possible to construct such a triangle.

An isosceles triangle with two sides of $10$ and the middle angle of $40$ degrees will have a base of $6.8404...$, not 7.